# Firemonkey TVertScrollBox mouse position

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

I have form (Height = 500) and TVertScrollBox on it (align set to TAlignLayout.Client and range is 5000px). I wrote simple method, which show position of mouse when I click on scroll box.

```
procedure TformMain.VertScrollBox1MouseDown(Sender: TObject;
  Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin
  ShowMessage(FloatToStr(X) + '  ' + FloatToStr(Y));
end;
```

When the scroll bar is on top and I click on top of the scroll box, Y in message is 0. That's right. But when I scroll down to the half and click on top of the scroll box, Y in message is 0, too (not 2500). How can I get the position relative to scroll box?

**This is my FMX code for TForm and TVertScrollBox:**

```
object formMain: TformMain
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  BorderIcons = [biSystemMenu, biMinimize]
  BorderStyle = Single
  Caption = 'Gear Studio 1.0'
  ClientHeight = 600
  ClientWidth = 450
  Position = DesktopCenter
  StyleBook = StyleBookPanel
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  OnCloseQuery = FormCloseQuery
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object VertScrollBox1: TVertScrollBox
    Align = Client
    Size.Width = 450.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 576.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    StyleLookup = 'VertScrollBox1Style1'
    TabOrder = 1
    OnMouseDown = VertScrollBox1MouseDown
    Viewport.Width = 450.000000000000000000
    Viewport.Height = 576.000000000000000000
  end
  ...
  ...
end
```

**That's how I am adding panels:**

```
  SetLength(MyItems, i+1);
  MyItems[i] := TItem.Create(i);
  with MyItems[i] do begin
    ...
  end;

constructor TItem.Create(number: integer);
var
  ThisItem: TItem;
begin
  inherited Create(nil);
  ThisItem := Self;
  with ThisItem do begin
    if number = -1 then begin
       ... //not important
      end;
    end else if number > 0 then begin
      Width := 370;
      Height := 35;
      ...
    end;
    Position.X := 10;
    Parent := formMain.VertScrollBox1;
    PopupMenu := formMain.PopupMenu1;
    OnDblClick := DblClick;
    OnMouseEnter := MouseEnter;
    OnMouseLeave := MouseLeave;
  end;
end;
```

MyItems is dynamical array of TItem (it is normal TPanel with added some properties).

Comment: I'm assuming this is under the Win32 platform? Also, there is no `alClient` on Delphi XE8 Firemonkey. It's `TAlignLayout.Client`. `alClient` is VCL (and older FMX).

Comment: Sorry, yes, it is Client.

Comment: Just tested and it works perfectly for me. How exactly are you setting this "range"? `TVertScrollBox` has no such property. This is defined by the controls contained within.

Comment: It was only example. Simple I have many `TPanel` in column in this `TVertScrollBox`.

Comment: I tested with a single `TPanel` with small width and a height of 5000. Can you show the `FMX` code of your form design so I can reproduce this? Also, are you clicking on one of these panels, or on the actual `TVertScrollBox`? I'm still assuming this is under Win32.

Comment: I am clicking on `TVertScrollBox`.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I don't see any panels here though. Are you adding them dynamically? If so, you should show how they're added. The way you're adding these panels may explain the reason this is happening.

Comment: I've added the code already. :)

Comment: Yes, you added the code 11 minutes after I asked for it. Not sure what the problem is, could be in the area where you say `//not important`.

Comment: Nope, there is code to create another type of `TItem` (different Size and some other properties).

Comment: I created new FMX form, added `TVertScrollBox` (align set to Client) and into it `TPanel`with Height = 5000. Same result. I don't understand. Please can you send me your working code? Thanks.

Comment: There is no code in my test besides the one single line as you have in your question. Precisely the same. What exact XE8 build do you have? I'm using 22.0.19908.869 Update 1. X is reporting correctly?

Comment: X is reporting correctly. I am using XE8 Version 22.0.19027.8951.

Comment: Please show me your FMX code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `VertScrollBox1.ViewportPosition.Y` property to get the absolute coordinate.

```
ShowMessage(FloatToStr(X) + '  ' + FloatToStr(VertScrollBox1.ViewportPosition.Y+Y));
```

shows correct result.

Comment: Maybe it's because you have newer version of XE8. :)